# ListVectorPlot with absolute vector sizes?

Tags: plotting

How can the size of the bounding circle around a vector point be controlled/fixed?
It apparently scales somewhat with the density of points.

Example:

```
points = Table[{Sin[i \[Pi]/8], Cos[i \[Pi]/8]}, {i, 16}];
vectors = Table[{i, i}, {i, 16}];
Show@Table[
  ListVectorPlot[Transpose[{points, vectors}][[;; ;; s]], 
   VectorPoints -> points[[;; ;; s]], VectorMarkers -> "CircleArrow", 
   VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
   VectorStyle -> Hue[1/s], VectorSizes -> {1, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> 1.5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   GridLines -> Automatic], {s, {1, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `VectorScaling -> None`

Comment: Not the answer, it makes all vectors in ONE plot the same size but still different size between plots of different point density. Just try it. P.S. I am on 12.3.1